# why when I start my JSF2 application on jboss EAP 6.3 it doesn't display in the inputText the value i set in the Managed Bean?

Tags: jsf-2, jboss

i have a simple file.xhtml in a JSF2.2 application, that's its code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"

xmlns:ez="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/ezcomp">

<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:form id="greeting">

<h:inputText id="num1" value="#{jSFeatBean.num1}"  />

<h:inputText id="num2" value="#{jSFeatBean.num2}"/>
<h:commandButton type="submit"
   value="Submit"
   action="#{jSFeatBean.addNumbers()}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{jSFeatBean.result}"/>!

</h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my @ManagedBean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "jSFeatBean", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class JSFeatursBean {

private String result; 
public int num1 = 1;
int num2;





public int getNum1() {
    return num1;
}

public void setNum1(int num1) {
    this.num1 = num1;
}

public int getNum2() {
    return num2;
}

public void setNum2(int num2) {
    this.num2 = num2;
}

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public Object addNumbers() {
        setResult("il risultato e': "+ Integer.toString(num1+num2));
    return null;
}
}
```

after i start jboss from Eclipse the browser display all elements of my file.xhtml properly but the values in the first (id = num1) inputText is 0 and not 1. Why this happens? If i put new values in the inputText boxes everything works fine, so i think that the Mbean is instantiated and working.
I have the same problem with a h:SelectOneListbox element, that doesn't show the list i create when i call the MBean constructor.
It looks like the MBean gets instatiated right after the display of html page.

Comment: To avoid the obvious, did you properly clean, rebuild and redeploy before restart?

Comment: yes, but it didn't change...two days ago i had some problems displaying tag elements in the html ( but jboss didn't give me error), in the end i found out i had to upgrade to Mojarra 2.2.12...i did and i solved that problem..regarding the set value, I can't remember if before upgrade everything worked fine ..
Do you think i have to upgrade something else? or maybe during upgrade something changed?i am using JSF 2.2 and servlet version is 3.1

Comment: ok i did the clean again properly, it works now! thanks!
i was going crazy about it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me with just one thing that might cause the problem.

Try remove "eager = true" attribute in your ManagedBean annotation. "eager = true" only works with ApplicationScoped Beans.